# SSLError Certificate Verify Failed Python API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Vehicle Model.py", line 12, in <module>
    response = requests.get(URL_PATTERN1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

I get the above error after compiling my code. I am currently using Edmunds API to extract specific items from their API. I don't know why I don't get this error message when I compile on other computers.

Then when I add:

```
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
urllib2.urlopen("https://no-valid-cert", context=context)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Vehicle Model.py", line 10, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen("https://no-valid-cert", context=context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Comment: When I add the line:                                                                           context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
urllib2.urlopen("https://no-valid-cert", context=context) Then I get another error: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

Answer (score 0):

You should first verify that everything is set up correctly with `curl`.  Here are the steps I would use:

```
curl --version
curl -v https://api.edmunds.com/
# this latter should verify that SSL and libcurl are working properly on the computer
```

If both of those work, then requests should also work.  If you want to use requests without verifying SSL, you can use the [`verify`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) parameter to `get`.

```
session.get('https://api.edmunds.com/', verify=False)
```